# Script that goes through multiple links

Tags: javascript

I am very new to scripting macros through web browsers I am trying to figure out how to pause mid script until the page loads again. I need to go though multiple links in order to delete these junk boxes except for the first one. With the way my code is now, it will delete just one box I assume because it doesn't wait for the page to load and then go to the next link.

```
var cancelButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("button-ico red_ui").length;

var link;
//start at 1 to skip the first
for (i = 1; i < cancelButtons; i ++) {

link = document.getElementsByClassName("button-ico red_ui")[i].href;
// by going to this link it deletes what I want it to
// only goes through one link though, can I pause it somehow until it's ready?
window.location.href = link;

}
```

One way I just thought of while writing this is I could open the links in separate tabs and close them at the end and reload the page. I may explore that if there is no better option.

Thanks for looking at my post!

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand what you are trying to achieve. If you are trying to open multiple windows you can do it with `window.open`. You can persist data between pages with localStorage or cookies.

Comment: Assigning to `window.location` reloads the page from that URL. The current page is replaced, and scripts in the current page stop running.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Part of my job is having to go through and delete several boxes by clicking these red buttons in the corner of the box (my job sucks lol). By looking at the source code I can see that the buttons are just links, and when you click the link the page refreshes with the one box deleted. So I am just trying a way to speed up that process sometimes there are like 40 boxes to delete. So with window.location that would stop a script in the console or imacro? Bummer, I will try window.open on monday to see if I can open several tabs and close them and refresh.

Comment: Hello Everyone, I got this to work in the javascript console. It works pretty well still have to manually close the original page but it updates and does what I want. Sorry it took me a while to reply to this I got side tracked.

var windows = [];

var domains = document.getElementsByClassName('red_ui');
for(var i = 1; i < domains.length; i++){
 
     windows.push(window.open(domains[i].attributes['href'].value));
    }


function closeW() {
 
//leave the last page open 
 for(var i = 0; i < windows.length-1; i ++) {
  windows[i].close();
 }
}

setTimeout(closeW,2000);

Comment: Only problem is Imacros stops the script with the new tab like what Barmar said earlier. Any apps out there that can run a script more like the javascript console? Thanks everyone!